# Why volume preservation is important for Metropolis update?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo, mcmc-acceptance-rate

I think my question is naive but I would like to ask why why volume preservation is important for MCMC and specifically Metropolis update.I'm reading the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1901.pdf where it says

> The significance of volume preservation for MCMC is that we needn’t
>   account for any change in volume in the acceptance probability for
>   Metropolis updates. If we proposed new states using some arbitrary,
>   non-Hamiltonian, dynamics, we would need to compute the determinant of
>   the Jacobian matrix for the mapping the dynamics defines, which might
>   well be infeasible.

where the Metropolis update for HMC is defined by

$\alpha=min\left \{1,exp\big(-H(q^{*},p^{*})+H(q,p)\big)  \right \}$

where $q$ denotes the position and $p$ denotes the momenta and $(q^{*},p^{*})$ is the proposed state.

What would be the problem for $\alpha$ if we had different volume for the proposed $(q^{*},p^{*})$.